# How to disable ctrl-c in a non-interactive bash script and its git subprograms

Tags: bash, copy-paste, bash-trap

I am calling git clone from a non-interactive bash shell.  It is non-interactive because it is launched from a Windows Explorer contect menu. I am running git version 2.20.1.windows.1 on Windows 10 64-bit.

I am running Git/usr/bin/bash -l -e 'myscript' in a Git/usr/bin/mintty window launched from the context menu.

I want to block the user from interrupting the git clone with ctrl-c.

I tried:

```
set -m
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM (2 single quotes)
git clone ... &
wait -n
echo $?
```

The ctrl-c passes through to the git clone which exits. I assume it has a signal handler that exits on SIGINT. I would like to know why this does not work.

I tried:

```
saved=$(stty -g)
stty -isig
git clone ...
stty "$saved"
```

The stty fails with "stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device" because there is no tty for a non-interactive bash shell.  So how is the ctrl-c getting to the git clone if there is no tty?

I am testing with git clone, but want to deploy this for git pull and git push.  Our developers have caused their local repos to be inconsistent by interrupting a long git pull with ctrl-c.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works on Linux. Sounds like an issue specific to Windows and GitBash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes that handle signals themselves (examples seem to be `git`, `ping` and `scp`) prevent the parent `trap` from being called.

So this simple example won't fit these purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM
sleep 10
```

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350056/87264) suggests using `set -m` (processes run in separate process group) in a subshell which does not send SIGINT to the the process:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM
uninterruptableCommand="git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/"
( set -m; $uninterruptableCommand & wait )
```

WARNING: the example is a really long-running command. You can still send signals to the process directly (e.g. `pkill git`).

Comment: Sleep does not catch signals.  Git does and so does ping for example.  Try your example with ping -n 20 google.com.  Many other postings confirm this.

Comment: @gitrdone thank you for that correction. I have not thought about that. I updated my answer to break signal delivery to the subprocess.

Comment: Did you happen to notice that I have already tried that in my original posting?

Comment: It requires the subshell IMHO

Comment: I did not catch the () distinction, the & control operator to run a job in the background starts a subshell.  I tried the () and the clone is still interrupted by the ctrl-c.  I am beginning to agree with @that other guy, that Windows bash or mintty works differently.

Comment: mea culpa - actually two bash shells were involved, one that emulates a spinner which calls one that initiates the git clone.  I put the trap in the child bash and the result was that the parent bash terminated on a ctrl-c and closed the window.  In the meantime, the git clone was still running and actually completed.  A simple ps -ef told the tale.   Moving the trap to the parent bash solved the problem.